# Firefox browser is not loading with Error: typeError: addon is null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class firstTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\SOFTWARE\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

While executing above code I am getting following error :

```
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\DEEPAK D P\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 3345: TypeError: addon is null
1521607690370   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/59.0.1/20180315233128/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-GB/release/Windows_NT%2010.0.0.0.16299.125%20(x64)/default/default/update.xml
1521607691520   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1521607692630   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1521607692638   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-c492c1
1521607698968   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1521607698976   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-47ef79

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at tests.firstTest.main(firstTest.java:22)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
driver@googlecode.com
1521607670798   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\xxx \AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4306519380516409248webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1521607670798   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping activity-stream@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\activity-stream@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping followonsearch@mozilla.com to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\followonsearch@mozilla.com.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping formautofill@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\formautofill@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping onboarding@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\onboarding@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping screenshots@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670800   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1521607670802   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on activity-stream@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670802   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670802   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1521607670802   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
1521607670802   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670804   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on onboarding@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670804   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670804   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on shield-recipe-client@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670804   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1521607670806   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1521607670806   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1521607670806   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} in app-global
1521607670806   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1521607670806   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {}
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\DEEPAK D P\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 3345: TypeError: addon is null
1521607690370   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/59.0.1/20180315233128/WINNT_x86_64-msvc-x64/en-GB/release/Windows_NT%2010.0.0.0.16299.125%20(x64)/default/default/update.xml
1521607691520   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
1521607692630   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1521607692638   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-c492c1
1521607698968   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
1521607698976   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to C:\Users\DEEPAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpaddon-47ef79

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: '192.168.43.34', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at tests.firstTest.main(firstTest.java:22)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
driver@googlecode.com
1521607670798   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\DEEPAK D P\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4306519380516409248webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1521607670798   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
```

Comment: `TypeError: addon is null` is a redundant harmless _INFO_. Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
 at tests.firstTest.main(firstTest.java:22)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
driver@googlecode.com

Comment: Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'DaffyDeepak', ip: '192.168.43.34', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)

Comment: Update the main question with this information for a proper analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: '192.168.43.34', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

The error trace logs clearly mention that *Browser Client* is unable to recognize back the *FirefoxDriver* binary.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.48.2** of **2015-10-09 19:59:12** which is almost **2.5 years** older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_40** which is pretty ancient.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Firefox* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u40* , *Selenium Client v2.48.2*.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v59.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Firefox* base version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Firefox*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: @DeepakSabastein Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you for the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium version affected the test execution. When I upgraded it to 3.11.0 the test is working fine..

Thanks...